# Detect Scroll Event on NSButton

Tags: swift, macos, nsevent

How can I detect a scroll event on an NSButton?

I have already found some pages telling me about global and local event listeners but now I'm not quite sure, how I can use them.

Comment: What do you mean by "a scroll event on an NSButton"? A scroll wheel event?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, a scroll wheel event.

Comment: Override `scrollWheel(with:)`.

Comment: That seems great, but I'm still not sure how I can implement that. My starting point is a simply a button `let button = NSButton()`. What I would think is that I have to initialize a new local NSEvent listener. But this always resolves in an error. Would you mind giving me a simple example?

Comment: Subclass `NSButton`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked perfectly.